# how to fetch from firebase and passing a value to a variable

Tags: json, firebase, url, constants, react-native

I want to fetch a value from firebase/json and put it on these variable. I just want to manipulate these variable.

```
var data1 = "";
var data2 = "";
var data3 = "";
var data4 = "";
var data5 = "";
var data6 = "";
var url = [
  {
    "videourl": data1,
  },
  {
    "videourl": data2,
  },
  {
    "videourl": data3,
  },
  {
    "videourl": data4,
  },
  {
    "videourl": data5,
  },
  {
    "videourl": data6,
  },
];
```

Comment: there is lot of resource for firebase fetch values, but cant find any particular answer that can be fetched a value and put in a particular variables

Comment: @Dhaval Jardosh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*This isn't a complete answer, just 1 part of the task, will post next steps in just a while*

[**Firebase Official Documentation**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

```
// Import Admin SDK
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Get a database reference to our posts
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog/posts");

// Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());

  //Check what you get here in the console.
}, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

Comment: Still looking into it. :)